# In OBJECT tag the heap setting is not working

Tags: java, memory, applet, jvm

We can set JVM heap setting like

```
<APPLET CODE="Main.class" WIDTH="800" HEIGHT="500">
<PARAM name="separate_jvm" value="true">
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-Xmx512M">
```

Can we do this in `<OBJECT>` tag?  It's working for me.  Is there any other way?

Comment: Is Tag some Java-like language? *What* is working for you? Or if you meant to write that it's *not* working for you, what exactly are you trying? Currently your question is really unclear.

Comment: Please be sure to check the post in the preview before hitting 'post'!  Also note that HTML will typically vanish unless using code formatting.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have asituation in which i want to set the jvm heap seize at run time. Is this possible? System.setProperty(V m options....) does not work bcz the jvm is launched before executing this code.... So is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to deploy this applet is using [`deployJava.js`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html).  Once you have the parameters & attributes correct, it will write the correct form of the correct element for whatever browser loads it.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Actually my deployjava.js does not have <html or object tag> Shall i add it and do like this... then my application will use this memory what i set by java_arguments...?

Comment: *"my deployjava.js does not have <html or object tag>"*  I have no idea what you are trying to express there.  Can you use other words?

Comment: Actually i am working in a maintainance project, I need to set jvm max heap at run time, i found several ways but after jvm launch nothing is setting heap to a different value.and  this project deployment.js only cheking for the correct jre installed in the system or not. Kindly suggest that could help in this scenario...

Comment: The point is that the `deployJava.js` will write the correct element to embed an applet.  The `java_arguments` parameter will be acted on if it is correctly written, and the JRE is recent enough (older JREs do not support the `java_arguments` attribute).

Comment: thank you for help. Is there any way to do it by writting this java_arguments in <object> tag directly...?Bcz my application does not use the deployjava.js's html page to load in browser!

Comment: *"Is there any way to do it by writting this java_arguments in <object> tag directly...?"*  I guess so, since the script manages to do it.

Comment: thanks a lot. Actually in my system next gen plug in was disabled that's why it was not working.   Thak you very much for your help.